# Some Logo and Stamp on Mathematics and Mathematicians

Tags: math-history

I don't know whether this question is allowed to post of stackexchange, but I don't know other any other so good sources of mathematics community other than this website. I also thought that the answer to my following questions can be best understood from mathematicians involved in the stackexchange community.

**1** There is a (French) [stamp](http://www.1902encyclopedia.com/A/ALG/algebra-14.html) in the honor of Augustin Cauchy, and there are two figures on the stamp. On the right hand side, there is Cauchy's famous integral formula in Complex Analysis. I couldn't see what the left figure in the stamp represents? I saw different images of the stamp online, but couldn't understood the left figure in the stamp.

**2** The logo of Mathematical Association of America is Icosahedron. Definitely, it was chosen with some mathematical thought related to Icosahedron. What is the reason behind choosing this logo?

I mention that, the Mathematics Intelligencer, published by Springer, is providing informations about stamps involving mathematics and mathematicians for many years. Since I saw only recent issues of this Intelligencer, one may inform me if there is any information, related to my two questions, published some years ago in the Intelligencer.

(I apologize for any mistake while writing the question.)

Comment: The LH image on the stamp appears to be showing how the area under an parabola is found via integral calculus. Don't know how that goes with Cauchy, though.